# Returning values of entry fields with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a request form and return the values of each field for storage in a DB later.

I can't seem to get the values back from the entry fields using the .get method on them in my submit button?

```
#imported modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#declared
window = Tk()
spares = IntVar()

#window config
window.title("Histology Further Work")
window.geometry('600x400')
window.configure(background = "light grey")

#combobox for option selection
comboEx = ttk.Combobox(window, values=[" ***Select*** ", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"])
comboEx.current(0)
comboEx.grid(row = 6, column = 1)
print(comboEx.current(), comboEx.get())

#return values
def click_me():
    print(spares.get())
    print(comboEx.get())
    print(b1.get())

#field labels
a1 = Label(window, text = "Cassette ID").grid(row = 0,column = 0)
a2 = Label(window, text = "Block ID").grid(row = 1,column = 0)
a3 = Label(window, text = "Surname").grid(row = 2,column = 0)
a4 = Label(window, text = "Test required").grid(row = 3,column = 0)
a5 = Label(window, text = "Spares on case?").grid(row = 4,column = 0)
a6 = Label(window, text = "Comments").grid(row = 5,column = 0)
a7 = Label(window, text = "Pathologist").grid(row = 6,column = 0)

#entry fields
b1 = Entry(window).grid(row = 0,column = 1)
b2 = Entry(window).grid(row = 1,column = 1)
b3 = Entry(window).grid(row = 2,column = 1)
b4 = Entry(window).grid(row = 3,column = 1)
b5 = Checkbutton(window, variable=spares).grid(row = 4,column = 1)
b6 = Entry(window).grid(row = 5,column = 1)


#submit button
btn = ttk.Button(window, text="Submit", command=click_me).grid(row = 7, column = 0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because those `Entry` widgets (b1, ..., b6) are all `None` as they are the result of `.grid(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not say `grid()` on same line as class declaration because `grid()` returns `None`.

```
b1 = Entry(window)
b1.grid(row = 0,column = 1)

b2 = Entry(window)
b2.grid(row = 1,column = 1)

b3 = Entry(window)
b3.grid(row = 2,column = 1)

b4 = Entry(window)
b4.grid(row = 3,column = 1)

b5 = Checkbutton(window, variable=spares).grid(row = 4,column = 1)

b6 = Entry(window)
b6.grid(row = 5,column = 1)
```

The same rule applies to `pack()` and `place()` too. But why is `b5` kept as it is? Because to get the value from `b5` we use `spares.get()` and not `b5.get()`.

Comment: Ah, I understand what I did wrong. Thank you very much! :)